# How to get data from Database which is stored in UTC

Tags: c#, asp.net, utc, quartz.net, timezone-offset

It's been a long time I am finding a solution to this problem and banging my head but I am very confused and hopeless. Actually, I am storing attendance time in server-side using `DateTime.Now` When user signs in from the web or phone I store the time on server-side like `attendanceData.DateNTime = DateTime.Now;` which is in UTC. Whenever users on the web want to see his/her data I am converting the UTC time to his/her local time using the below code.

```
 List<Model.Attendance> attendanceRecord = attendanceService.GetByDateAndId(this.LoginEmployeeId, DateTime.Now).OrderBy(x => x.DateNTime).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < attendanceRecord.Count(); i++)
        {
            attendanceRecord[i].DateNTime = 
            WebUtils.TimezoneDateConversion(attendanceRecord[i].DateNTime, 
            this.UserTimeZone);
        }
```

Here is TimezoneDateConversion method:

```
 public static DateTime TimezoneDateConversion(DateTime date, string timezoneid)
    {
        TimeZoneInfo infotime = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezoneid);
        //var dateTimeUTC = DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Local);
        var dateTimeSetKind = DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTimeSetKind, infotime);
    }
```

Let's have an example my local time is `1:40 AM 3/4/2022 Pakistan Standard Time` and server time is '8:40 PM 3/3/2022'. Now if I get my data on the web it will return me yesterday's data. Because UTC time is 5 hours behind. I know that I am using DateTime.Now in the query which will be UTC time and get data from the previous day and then I am converting all time to user timezone. I tried first converting server `DateTime.Now` to user local time then passing it to `GetByDateAndId` but it gives the wrong data.
I might be doing something wrong when fetching data from database.

Here is my server database:
[image: Server database]
Now when I fetch data using `DateTime.UTCnow` in LINQ it's showing me yesterday's data but I want data according to my local time.

Answer (score 0):

> When user signs in from the web or phone I store the time on server-side like `attendanceData.DateNTime = DateTime.Now;`

[`DateTime.Now`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=net-6.0) will return the local time of your server. From the docs:

> Gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time on this computer, expressed as the local time.

[`DateTime.UtcNow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.utcnow?view=net-6.0) will return the computers time as UTC time regardless of the timezone. From the docs:

> Gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time on this computer, expressed as the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

To solve the problem change this:

```
attendanceData.DateNTime = DateTime.Now;
```

to this:

```
attendanceData.DateNTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

If you can't change that line, another option you can take is to call `ToUniversalTime()` on the date before converting it, for example:

```
attendanceRecord[i].DateNTime = WebUtils.TimezoneDateConversion(attendanceRecord[i].DateNTime.ToUniversalTime(), this.UserTimeZone);
```

However, this is not a great solution because if you ever change the servers timezone that conversion will be incorrect. The better solution is storing UTC times in the first place.

Comment: Server time is actually UTC time so changing datetime.now to datetime.utcnow will not help.

Comment: Fair enough, I would still suggest using `DateTime.UtcNow' to be safe in the future but you're right it won't fix the issue you're having. Your code looks correct (when I have more time I can try it) so let's see if something else is going on. Can you check that the `this.UserTimeZone` in debug to ensure it's correct? In your example you mentioned "it will return me yesterday's data" what was the exact time that was returned? Just looking for more info to see what's going on :)

Comment: I ended up trying your code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PQXvJY) and using your example data it works fine. So there's something else going wrong. Check the values of `attendanceRecord[i].DateNTime` and `this.UserTimeZone` and add them to your question. You can also try putting a breakpoint after the for loop and inspect the values of `attendanceRecord` to see if they are correct. It's possible something after the for loop is changing the values

Comment: this.UserTimeZone is working fine it actually returns "Pakistan Standard Time" and it's converting my time correctly for example if UTC is 6:00 PM then it is showing 11:00 PM. The problem is when I am fetching data from database using LINQ it should first convert time to local time then pick the data. For example if UTC time is 9:00 PM 3/4/22 and my local time is 2:00 AM 3/5/22 now if I get my attendance for today then my LINQ in question will get data in UTC which is be prevouse day data. I hope you understand it.